# Two spies plan a secret meeting

Tags: cipher

Two spies meet in a city, near a cornerstone pillar, on 9/16/16.  One delivers a message to the other.  It says:

> Nones
>   5 4 7.3 9 10 11
>   12 1
>   9 4 11 9.4 '
>   1.1 11 11 4

They nod at each other in approval and then meet somewhere to continue their conversation over breakfast.

**Where do they meet and when?**

**Edit**: Please read all comments & attempts below.  I strongly believe all the necessary clues have been provided.

**Edit 2**: The bounty expired yet the answer was not given.  Hint:

> Give special thought to the what the line `12 1` means by itself and then in relation to the rest of the puzzle.

**Edit 2**: I gaze upon this riddle in horror!  Especially after reading the [sandbox rules](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5372/okay-the-sandbox-didnt-work-we-still-have-a-quality-problem-lets-figure-out?cb=1).  I shan't let it go stale!  Hint:

> The riddle's tag is cipher.  Therefore the numbers in the box map to letters that spell a location. Not geo-coordinates, although that is clever.

Comment: Past tense future date! Aaaahhh!

Comment: ..and tense is important

Comment: I'm betting 'Nones' is a key word

Comment: You're on Beastly!

Comment: Since it's been almost two days, can you post a hint?

Comment: @FrodCube I already did in the comments below.  I will again if need be.

Comment: @jmb.mage: Now, any more clues ? Just 4 days remaining when the spies will meet.

Comment: I am adding two clues. First is the apostrophe after 9.4. Second is the mention of a cornerstone pillar, which may help to guide you.

Comment: Now I really think that the clues needed are there, especially since @rand-althor figured out the when part below.

Comment: What's a cornerstone pillar?

Comment: Spies might use base 13, based on the grouping of the numbers. Then may be conversion to A1Z26.

Comment: Does the cornerstone pillar refer to the Hajj, a pillar of Islam? If so, then their original meeting would have been in Mecca?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been concluded in comments on other answers that the date of the next meeting is

> **October 7th**, because the term Nones refers to the 7th day of the upcoming long month. It could have also been the 5th day of the short month in which the first meeting was held, but that would imply going back in time, which is impossible.

In looking at the numbers in the map, we notice that

> all the numbers are less than 12. Nones is a Roman calendar keyword that identifies more than just the date, but also that months are the key to deciphering the letters.
>  Each whole number is the first letter of its corresponding month, and decimals represent which letter in those months names to use. *Given the Nones keyword, we are clued in that we should use the names of the months from the Roman calendar for this cipher.* For example, we have a 7.3 in the map. The seventh month is July, its Roman name is Quintilis, and its third letter is I.
>
> Following this pattern all the way through, we get the following:
>  **M A I S O N**
>  **D I**
>  **S A N T'**
>  **A N N A**
>  which is **La Maison di Sant'Anna in Roma, Italy** (coming full circle to realize it is a Roman location)
>
>  *Note: there is a mistake in the puzzle map, where the first number of the fourth line, 1.1, should actually refer to the second letter, not the first. Everything else matches up cleanly.*

Comment: Goddammit, I tried exactly this, but I couldn't think what to do with the decimals! :-/

Comment: Ah, that's what you meant! I thought you were intepreting $m.n$ as the $n$th letter of the name of the $m$th month, but that wouldn't give anything meaningful anyway.

Comment: How about if $m.n$ is the $(n+1)$th letter (i.e. $n$ letters after the start) of the name of the $m$th month? That would make sense since a non-decimal $m$ would correspond to $m.0$, and it gives everything perfectly except a Y instead of an I in MAISON, which is a fairly small difference.

Comment: Either a mistake, or else we're barking completely up the wrong tree with this method! I'm hoping for the former :-)

Comment: I got it. The Roman calendar would spell the months differently. January starts with an i, and July was actually called Quintilis. This fixes all our problems. I will update the answer to make it complete.

Comment: You got it, even with the spy's error!  Yes, the spy was confused between base 0 and base 1 numerics, but you saw through that!  Cheers!

Comment: @Bulldogg6404... Great.. I worked on it..But get only 50 % answer..i.e,, Nones..

Comment: @jmb.mage ...Great question. But what about Cornerstone pillar?

Comment: @SathiReddy it was to help them figure out it was in Rome, where there are many pillars.  Cornerstone is associated with the Cross in Christianity.

Answer (score 3):

My attempt:

5 4 7.3 9 10 11

> 5 4 7.3 9 10 11 represents map for a place in Cameroon

9 4 11 9.4

> 9 4 11 9.4 represents map for a place in Nigeria

1.1 11 11 4

> 1.1 11 11 4 represents map for a place in Equatorial Guinea. These three represents places in Africa. So they want to meet at a place in Africa.

It may be:

> Thies Nones. Thies Nones is a city found in Thies, Senegal(Africa).

Comment: What about 12 1? Also check the old edits: before changing all the past tenses the code was slightly different.

Comment: interesting use of geo-co-ordinates but missing 12 1 as @FrodCube states.  And that is an important part of the puzzle.

Comment: Ok. i will try..

Comment: @jmb.mage They meet on 5th september 2016. Because, according to Roman calendar Nones indicate 5th day of short months and 7th day of long months..

Comment: But i am not getting what is 12 1

Comment: @SathiReddy you got one of the clues but they definitely can't meet in the past.

Comment: @jmb.mage 7th of October then? (the next Nones in the future)

Answer (score 1):

> 5 4 7.3 9 10 11: 54.73 91.011. 54.73ºN 91.011ºE redirects to a place in Russia, in the province of Krasnoyarsk Krai.
>  12.1, next. 12 January.
>  9 4 11 9.4 ', 9.4'N, and 94.11E. Andaman Sea. 
>  1.1 11 11 4. 1.111N 11.4W, which redirects to the extremely far coast of Liberia.
>  Now we have gotten that all set up, lining up and finding the center lands us in a place between Eman, Iran and Dehaj, Iran. In there, there is only desert and rock.

This concludes they are gonna meet at 12 January in the middle of nowhere, in Iran. Or in coordinates, 30.924774N, 54.506811E

Comment: In a comment, the OP has already confirmed that the date of the meeting is 7 October, which was found in a comment to the other answer. Also, 12 1 seems to have a special significance.